# Publish Angular 4 to Azure

Tags: angular, azure

Using `Ng Build` command I have published Angular-4 app into dist folder. Then uploaded to Azure Web App. All files are uploaded to IIS server properly. Here is image from KUDU site. 
[image]

> However Chrome is not able to locate these files. Errors in Console are 404. Strange!
>   Any pointers in right direction would be much appreciated.
>   [image]

Answer (score 1):

did you check your index.html, especially the base href ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have web.config file defined? Without it IIS wouldn't know where to look for the files (index.html).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension="json" mimeType="application/json" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension="woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension="woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
</staticContent>             
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="SPA" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*\.(js|json|txt|css|map|html|ttf|woff|woff2|eot|svg|png)$" negate="true" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```